# Trying to Query 2 Access tables with 1 statement

Tags: c#, ms-access

I've been doing research and cannot find a way to get data from multiple tables using one query. What I want to achieve is getting information from one table in an Access database and using that information to get more data from a different table in the same database

Here's the code I have so far...

```
                string end = "ENDDATE";
                string qual = "CGA0113";
                string start = "START";

                ad.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT* FROM [AC_ECONOMIC] Where KEYWORD = '" + end + "'AND QUALIFIER = '" + qual + "' AND EXPRESSION LIKE 'SN%'", con);
```

I want to be able to get data from a separate table called AC_PROPERTY with the same SN from the query above from that AC_ECONOMIC table. I was researching joins and believe that is the way to go but I'm not quite sure of the syntax or if that would even work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to use the `JOIN` keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, an inner join would be the way to go. You basically need to construct a statement that joins the 2 tables by their common field. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [AC_ECONOMIC] a
INNER JOIN [AC_PROPERTY] b
on [AC_ECONOMIC].SN=[AC_PROPERTY].SN   
Where KEYWORD = '" + end + "'AND QUALIFIER = '" + qual + "' AND EXPRESSION LIKE 'SN%'
```

Above statement is just an example. I don't know if the common column between the 2 tables is actually called "SN".

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by @Geek, you can also alias the tables after you reference them in your statement, this saves you from typing the full table names every time. For example, the above statement can also be written as:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM [AC_ECONOMIC] a
INNER JOIN [AC_PROPERTY] b
on a.SN=b.SN   
Where a.KEYWORD = '" + end + "'AND a.QUALIFIER = '" + qual + "' AND b.EXPRESSION LIKE 'SN%'
```

Note how the WHERE clause is filtering using columns from both, "a" (AC_ECONOMIC) and b (AC_PROPERTY).

Comment: I would alias these to ensure the filter columns are being filtered on the correct table.  This is just a personal preference.  SELECT 
* 
FROM [AC_ECONOMIC] a
INNER JOIN [AC_PROPERTY] b
on a.SN=b.SN   
Where a.KEYWORD = '" + end + "'AND a.QUALIFIER = '" + qual + "' AND a.EXPRESSION LIKE 'SN%'

Comment: Sorry one more question, would I be able to select certain columns from the AC_PROPERTY table with this method?

Comment: @Stick yes, if you alias `[AC_PROPERTY]` as `a` for example, you can write: `SELECT a.SN, a.QUALIFIER from [AC_PROPERTY] a where ... ` You follow? If you need to select columns from both tables, refer to my update and instead of writing `a.*` or `b.*` you instead can write `select a.SN, b.EXPRESSION from ... ` that way you don't select everything (*) from both tables and just the columns you are interested in from each.

Comment: Ahhhh yes I follow you, thanks a lot for the help it is much appreciated.